# Concatenate two numbers to create a title in one cell

Tags: numbers, concatenation, title

for experiments we use an excel sheet to mark the results. This question is about creating the title of each column. So the title should be T1h(20°C), where the number 1 and number 20 are variables. So my question is if we can create a formula that asks the two specific variables and returns it in a complete title?

this is the formula until now: =TEXT(IF(ISBLANK(D51); "";IF(ISBLANK(D52); ""; CONCATENATE(D51; "T"; D52; "°C")));"#")
So I am filling in the variables in two different cells and with the formula hope to return it into a completed title.

Comment: ok, found this solution. Before I post it I did move the check table with cells D51 and D52 to another tab. this is reflected in the solution where D51 is now B4 and D52 is now C4: ="T " &'Template Dashboard'!$B$4 & "h " &"(" &'Template Dashboard'!$C$4 & "°C)". This returns the expected title "T1h (20°C)".